# The difference between defining impl within a function and defining it outside a function

Tags: rust

When I was looking at `The Rust Programming Language`, I found a piece of code like this (https://rust-book.cs.brown.edu/ch05-03-method-syntax.html#method-calls-are-syntactic-sugar-for-function-calls):

```rust
struct Point(i32, i32);
fn main() {
   let p = Point(1, 2);
   impl p {
     fn x(&self) -> i32 { self.0 }
   }
  
   println!("{}", p.x());
}
```

**This program does not compile.** But I suddenly wanted to try if I could create an impl block for the structure within the function.
My attempt finally succeeded, and I was indeed able to create an impl block for the structure within the function. At first I thought that the impl block within the function could only take effect within the current function scope, but when I ran the test, the impl block outside the scope Functions can also use impl blocks from other scopes, which puzzles me. I've even tried not executing the function containing the impl block, but this still works in other functions.
[go rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=87f9a6e5ed8e4d1775b0010c096513d3)

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
struct Rectangle {
    width: u32,
    height: u32
}

impl Rectangle {
    fn area(&self) -> u32 {
        self.width * self.height
    }
}

fn test_normal() {
    let r = Rectangle { width: 2, height: 2 };
    
    println!("fn test_normal: {}", r.area());
}

fn test_block_impl() {
    impl Rectangle {
        fn square(size: u32) -> Self {
            Self { width: size, height: size }
        }
    }
    
    let r = Rectangle::square(4);
    
    println!("fn test_block_impl: {}", r.area());
}

fn test_outside() {
    let r = Rectangle::square(6);
    
    println!("fn test_outside: {}", r.area());
}


fn main() {
    let r = &mut Box::new(Rectangle { width: 1, height: 2 });
    
    let area1 = r.area();
    let area2 = Rectangle::area(&**r);
    assert_eq!(area1, area2);
    
    test_normal();
    // test_block_impl();
    test_outside();
    // test_block_impl();
}
```

This makes me very confused, why this program can run normally, I did not explicitly call `test_block_impl` in the main function 
I've tried asking GPT but it doesn't give me the same answer as it actually does...
[image]

--- Expand ---
I found a website that allowed me to look at assembly code, which was really useful for me in understanding what the Rust compiler was doing, and hopefully it will help others too: https://godbolt.org
[image]

Comment: Side-note since the question has already been answered. In Rust you can almost put anything inside of a function. The funny thing is, you're more limited to what you can put inside an `impl`, than what you can put inside an `fn`. You can also put `mod` inside of an `fn`. So you could do stuff like `fn { mod { impl { fn { mod { ... } } } } }`. See [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f8d05f30ea3a5a18532e7107eac21d2b)

Comment: @vallentin Wow, this looks a bit crazy , actually, I'd rather understand the scope in which they work

Comment: it does have some benefits. For instance the code for [doc tests](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rustdoc/write-documentation/documentation-tests.html) are implicitly wrapped in `fn main() { ... }`. So if it wasn't possible to put `use`, `fn`, `mod`, `impl` inside of an `fn`. Then there are various cases where doc tests would fail to compile, and need special handling

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`impl` is not affected by where it is declared. It always takes place, even nested inside things (functions, modules, consts...).

Do note, however, that it is discouraged to define `impl` in any other place except directly under module (with a little exception: inside anonymous const `const _: () = { ... }` it is fine, because macros want this). Such impls won't be discovered by rust-analyzer, and [there is an accepted RFC to lint and eventually reject them](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/3373-avoid-nonlocal-definitions-in-fns.html).

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. I now understand that some code blocks defined in fn will take effect at any time. Now, I should check the documentation to see what other keywords will take effect globally.

Comment: @Haceral I think it's only `impl`. Basically, everything that affects outside types, since types cannot have states and cannot track "was this function called".